# Are there plugins available for an "improved" Find Content admin interface?

Tags: nodes, theming

One of our clients has a lot of content over a number of languages and has expressed that they don't really like the Filter/Sort options available on the Find Content page.

Are there any plugins available that present this information in a different manner...maybe something like Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module? that, allows you create custom admin interface.

Comment: Thanks for the plugin could be useful on other projects, but not quite what this client is looking for. They want something that makes its easier to navigate through their content to manage it; something like a folder viewer where each page is a folder...strange request I know.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by each page is a folder? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Non-technical people get used to certain idioms like folders and files. We've had more than one client complain about the Find Content page and the difficulty in finding the content that they're looking for. If the "Our Company" page is under the "About Us" page, they sometimes expect to have to go to "About Us" first, then to the "Our Company" page. Just curious if someone came up with a different Content Management interface for Drupal.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything (would love to be proven wrong though); it's a very difficult concept to make generic. What constitutes a 'folder'? Is it a taxonomy term reference? A menu hierarchy (in which case what happens when some of the menu items link to non-content pages)? If it's done by menu links, what happens when a piece of content has stuff under it in the hierarchy? Technically that content should be a folder, but it's also a file...because of the difficulty in defining these things I don't it would be an easy thing to do

Comment: An odd request for sure...if I find, or develop something, I'll let you know ;)

Comment: Agree with Clive. 'Technically that content should be a folder, but it's also a file'  . So explorer / finder style will not be suitable.

Comment: @SomethingOn Please do, I'd love to get that particular recurring complaint off my back too!